# What is the Gtk event called when a window minimizes?

Tags: c, events, signals, gtk

If I want some function to be called when a window gets closed I connect with `delete_event`. What should I connect with if I want the function to be called when the user minimizes a Gtk Window. Something like: `minimize_event`? I couldn't find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was at the very same crossroads, wth only some info and code on python gtk, but not in C.

After looking the docs again and again I realized I got confuse by same sounding names, unions, structures and enums and bitfields. I was handling things as booleans, when it was a bitfield thingy all along.

First:

```
g_signal_connect(
    G_OBJECT(window), 
    "window-state-event", 
    G_CALLBACK(callback_func), 
    userDataPointer);
```

Then:

```
gboolean callback_func(
    GtkWidget *widget,
    GdkEventWindowState *event,
    gpointer user_data)
{
    //some code
    //Minimized window check
    if(event->new_window_state & GDK_WINDOW_STATE_ICONIFIED){
    //some other code
}
//some more other code
return TRUE;
}
```

Remember this are bitfields and `&` is the "bit and" operator **not** the boolean `&&`.
`GDK_WINDOW_STATE_ICONIFIED =2` or `10` in binary
and `event->new_window_state` is an `int` of which the second bit is active

A Widget can be both maximized **and** minimized at the same time,
`GDK_WINDOW_STATE_MAXIMIZED = 4` or `100`

If you minimized a maximized window its`event->new_window_state = 6` or 110

You can experiment and see what works best for you.

More info:

- http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-window-state-event
- http://developer.gnome.org/gdk/stable/gdk-Event-Structures.html#GdkEventWindowState

Final Beware and caveats:

I'm using gtk+2, because of dual win&lin development. The newer gtk+3 might do some things different.

The [Gnome Developer Site](http://developer.gnome.org) site has some links broken or wrong, or partially re-writen, with some errors. The page on the first url I put above has

```
gboolean user_function (GtkWidget *widget,GdkEvent  *event,gpointer user_data){}
```

while the manual in the source code as well as other downloadable manuals has the correct:

```
gboolean user_function (
    GtkWidget *widget,
    GdkEventWindowState *event, 
    gpointer user_data){}
```

The page also has the [incorrect or broken link for the gtk3 page for `GdkEventWindowState`](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk-Event-Structures.html#GdkEventWindowState).
The gtk+3 version seems as wrong as the gtk+2, I have not seen the gtk+3 manuals with the source code or separate so I don't know if gtk+3 truly modifies the callback for the event and the gdk structures

For the moment as gtk+3 stabilizes**expect** inconsistencies. Use preferably the manuals that came with your source code or linux distro and version gtk+2.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Wow, thanks. I gotta hand it to you, I wasn't expecting such a complete answer after all the earlier ones. Thanks , problem solved. :)